# copy speed to server with multiple clients

Tags: copy, network-speed

I got a file server that is connected via an HP switch to multiple clients.
The clients are mapping network drives of shared folder on the server and copy files from an external e-sata drive to the server.

All adapters, switch and cables are 1Gbe. the connection on all machine indicate as 1.0Gbe

When a single client is copying files to the server, i'm getting nice copy speed, around 90MB/s.

When two clients are copying files to the server, i can see a drop down in the copy speed, to around 60MB/s per client.

Is it normal?

should the clients effect each other because of the 1Gbe bottleneck?
the server got a fast 16 drives raid so storage speed is not the issue.

Clients are a mix of Win 7 Pro x64 and Win XP Pro x32
and the server is Win Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Dori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  At 90MB/sec you are at .72 Gigabits/sec.  When you factor in protocol overheads, that's pretty good throughput.

Comment: so 1.0Gbe=125MB/s total throughput. And its normal to get a speed drop down when copying files from multiple machines to the same server?

Comment: There are multiple layers of protocols that add overhead, like TCP for example. You will not get 125MB/sec on a gigabit link at the application level.  As for the 'speed drop down', yes.  You have a maximum amount of data the physical link can handle.  It's basic division.